# Get Referrer URL including fragment identifier

Tags: javascript, html, url

I have a website embedded as `iframe` in another website, they are from different domains.

I need to get the url in the address bar including the part after hash sign (#) from the iframe. With `document.referrer` I can get everything until the hash, is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Given the standard [RFC2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616) (chapter 14.36) the [fragment identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier) is not included in the referrer header. The [JavaScript W3C definition](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-95229140) states a reference to a full URI as specified in [RFC2396](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt) which would include the fragment identifier.

While I see no technical reason a browser implementation could not give a full referrer in JavaScript I suppose the implementation is very close to the HTTP specs and maybe even browser dependent. To my knowledge all browsers implement the referrer in JavaScript without fragment identifier.

Comment: how would you do it then?

Comment: All modern browsers prohibit accessing the DOM of pages which are not in the same domain scope. This is a security feature. I would recommend you pass the fragment identifier to the IFRAME on load.